# How to start tomcat at boot time as a systemd service?

Tags: boot, systemd, tomcat

This is my Unit file:

```
# Systemd unit file for tomcat
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
Wants=network.target
After=syslog.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_OPTS=
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dnet.sf.ehcache.skipUpdateCheck=true -Xms2g -Xmx4g"

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Entering

```
systemctl enable tomcat
systemctl start tomcat
```

runs the service.
But when I reboot, I have to enter it again. I thought enabling the service would run it at boot time, too.

Any idea what to do or check next?

I looked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1390419/starting-tomcat-8-5-using-systemd-on-centos-7) and several other places, but without success.